# В оригинальном чужом репозитории новый релиз, в локальном клоне моего форка не готовые к коммиту черновики. Как всё объединить?

Tags: git, github

Объясните базовую вещь.
Локально работаю с клоном своего форка чужого репозитория. 
Много нарефакторил, но по ряду причин закоммитить пока не могу.

```
PS C:> git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/dev
  origin/master

PS C:> git branch
* dev-my-feature
  master
```

В то же время первоисточник выдал новый релиз, конфликтующий с моими изменениями. Я хочу дальше иметь обе ветки - и его, и мою (ту, где мои изменения приоритетны).

Прежде всего я не понимаю, как синхронизировать свой репозиторий с оригинальным.
Ну, и как сравнить свой незакоммиченный stash с чужим новым релизом.

Comment: Правильно внизу говорят, гуглите по понятию `topic branch`.

Answer (score 1):

> по ряду причин закоммитить пока не могу

Коммиты бесплатно делаются и их потом можно объединять. Делайте свои коммиты в новую ветку, а `master` обновляйте из оригинального репозитория, который форкнули.

> Прежде всего я не понимаю, как синхронизировать свой репозиторий с оригинальным

Нужно добавить оригинальный репозиторий как новый `remote`:

```
git remote add upstream git@github...
git fetch upstream
```

Теперь можно сравнивать вашу локальную ветку и `upstream/master`

Comment: Если коммиты ничего не стоят - то как запретить этому коммиту синхронизироваться с моим форком на гитхабе?  Не хочу такое публиковать.

Comment: @sundmoon сделайте его в другую ветку, не в `master`, и не пушьте эту ветку на гитхаб.

Comment: @sundmoon ну как, получилось? Задавайте вопросы, если что-нибудь ещё не ясно.